how to fix left and right skewness
I know that left and right skewness means it has a long tail on either the left(left skewness) or right(right skewness).
However, the example below is an example of right skewness.
data = pd.DataFrame({
  "Income": [15000, 22000, 30000, 35000, 42000, 50000, 65000, 78000, 120000, 250000]
})
sns.distplot( data['Income'] , color="skyblue", label="Sepal Length")


Now my understanding of right skewness is fewer data points on the increasing value of the x-axis. So is my understanding correct? and how do I fix this chart to be a normal distribution?
AFAIK, using central limit theorem I should be able to convert any shape to standard normal distribution but it requires a minimum sample size of 30. So in my case is there any other way or adding more data points is the only way?

Can I get some help on this?

You can transform your data to achieve a more normal distribution using the Yeo-Johnson Power Transformer, which also scales the data effectively. Here’s the code to implement it:
import pandas as pd  
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 

data = pd.DataFrame({
  "Income": [15000, 22000, 30000, 35000, 42000, 50000, 65000, 78000, 120000, 250000]
})

# Apply Yeo-Johnson Power Transformation to the "Income" data
data["Income_Normalized"] = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson').fit_transform(data[["Income"]])

# Plotting the distributions
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
for i, col in enumerate(["Income", "Income_Normalized"], 1):
    plt.subplot(1, 2, i)
    sns.histplot(data[col], bins=10, kde=True)
    plt.title(f'{"Normalized" if col == "Income_Normalized" else "Original"} Income Distribution')
    plt.xlabel('Income' if col == "Income" else 'Normalized Income')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Here are the graphs showing the original and normalized income distributions:


Thanks for the response buddy. But is my understanding correct?

Also are there any cons of using this algorithm?

The Central Limit Theorem is often misunderstood. It states that for a sufficiently large sample size (typically n ≥ 30), the distribution of the sample mean will approach normality, regardless of the original distribution. This applies to sample means, NOT the original data itself. To achieve normality in individual data points, transformations are necessary rather than simply increasing the sample size.

Cool. Can you also explain a bit about this method? I am just familiar with CLT and how fit_transform helps to achieve SND and also if there are any edge cases or cons in this algorithm.

Also, is my understanding of skewness correct as mentioned in the original post? Now my understanding of right skewness is fewer data points on the increasing value of the x-axis. 

Your understanding is almost correct. Right skewness means the distribution’s tail extends to the right, with most data points clustered on the left and fewer higher values pulling the tail outward. It’s not just the scarcity of points on the right but also the presence of outliers or extreme values that lengthen the tail.

Sorry, but I’m not entirely sure about the limitations of this method, but you can check the theory behind it and the documentation of the algorithm for more information.

Cool thanks @Gizem because I need to understand how this algorithm works before using it.
